# Why can't I open my tkinter app on Windows 8.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

[image: This is the screenshot]my tkinter executable is not working on windows 8.1, I've installed it on windows 10 and windows 8 before (running perfectly), but in my laptop which has windows 8.1 it shows **THIS APPLICATION CAN'T BE EXECUTED ON THIS DEVICE. check with software publisher**. I wonder what I'm missing.

Comment: Can you paste the exact text of the error?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the message I got , thanks

Comment: A screenshot seems more reliable here.

Comment: @CoolCloud hello mate, It's a windows system notification (windows 8.1), I haven't upload a picture beacuse It's in Spanish, so I just translated that message and type as well. anyway I'm gonna upload the image I hope it helps, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install it from pip

try to run these commands on cmd `pip uninstall pip` then `pip install pip`

appart from that i advice you to install windows 10.